# Como validar la lista de filtro de una tabla dinamica con VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy tratando de filtrar una tabla dinamica con vba, pero esta tabla la agregue al modelo de datos, cuanto le envio  los datos que tiene que filtar a la propiedad PivotFields me genera un error ya que algunos datos que mando a buscar no existen, la instruccion que uso es la siguiente:

```
.PivotFields("[Range].[Familia].[Familia]").VisibleItemsList = Array("[Range].[Familia].&[" & vArray(1, 1) & "]", "[Range].[Familia].&[" & vArray(2, 1) & "]", "[Range].[Familia].&[" & vArray(3, 1) & "]", "[Range].[Familia].&[" & vArray(4, 1) & "]")
```

y el vArray contiene los siguientes datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la table contiene los siguiente elementos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esa lista los unicos items que existen son  angulos y segundas, como hago para validar de esa lista que exite y filtrar por lo que eexiste.

gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Para validar si un ítem se encuentra dentro de un campo de una tabla dinámica, hay que recorrer todos los valores uno por uno. Cada campo `PivotField` te devuelve todos los valores con el método [`PivotItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.pivotitems).

Sería algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
Dim valorBuscado As String
valorBuscado = vArray(1, 1) 'tomo esto como ejemplo para buscar a uno solo


'Esta variable va a tener el resultado de si el valor está presente o no... La inicializamos como falso
Dim estaEntreLosValores As Boolean
estaEntreLosValores = False

'asignemos el campo a una variable, así es más fácil de leer
Dim campoFiltro As PivotField
Set campoFiltro = Tu_Tabla_Dinamica.PivotFields("[Range].[Familia].[Familia]")


Dim unItem As PivotItem

'y revisamos uno por uno
For Each unItem in campoFiltro.PivotItems
    If unItem.Name = valorBuscado Then
        ' encontrado!!!
        estaEntreLosValores = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Y así verificás si el valor `vArray(1, 1)` está dentro de los valores del filtro de la tabla dinámica... Luego será cuestión de revisar el resto de la lista de valores a validar.

Comment: Hola @Pollo gracias por tu respuesta, pero probe asi como dices y simplemente no toma los valores del pivotfields y por tal motivo no puedo generar la validacion es mas cuando llega al for each se lo salta como si no tuviera nada ese arregle